# how to add a task with in another task in capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

This is my `deploy.rb` and I have two tasks:

```
set :rpm_name,""
set :dir,"/tmp"

task :rpminfo do
        rpmofos1=capture("rpm -q #{rpm_name}")
        new_test
        puts "#{rpmofos1}"     
end

task :new_test do
        run "ls -ltr #{dir}"
end
```

I am invoking `cap` command as:

```
cap hostname rpminfo -s user=root -s dir=/root
```

This works fine for but I don't want to pass dir variable from command line instead I want that as:

```
task :rpminfo do
        rpmofos1=capture("rpm -q #{rpm_name}")
        new_test -s dir=/var
        puts "#{rpmofos1}" 
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the new_test definition in a helper method.

```
set :rpm_name,""
set :dir,"/tmp"

task :rpminfo do
        rpmofos1=capture("rpm -q #{rpm_name}")
        new_test_helper("/var")
        puts "#{rpmofos1}"     
end

def new_test_helper(path)
   run "ls -ltr #{path}"
end    

task :new_test do
   new_test_helper(dir)
end
```

But, if you don't like that idea, you can also set the variable temporarily before you call the sub-task.

```
set :rpm_name,""
set :dir,"/tmp"

task :rpminfo do
        rpmofos1=capture("rpm -q #{rpm_name}")
        old_dir = dir
        set :dir, "/tmp"
        new_test
        set :dir, old_dir
        puts "#{rpmofos1}"     
end

task :new_test do
        run "ls -ltr #{dir}"
end
```

The other way is much cleaner.